# How to pass value from return data to another script [mounted () ] in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, variables, vue-component

**From the test, I successfully return the value from res.data[0] to firstpoint[], but in the mounted() which I creating the chart, I can't pass the value from "firstpoint" to let test = "firstpoint".**

```
export default {
  extends: Line,
  props: ['height'],

  data() {
    return {
      firstpoint: [],
    };
  },

  async created() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "https://k67r3w45c4.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/TwitterTrends"
      );
      this.firstpoint = res.data[0].TweetVolume;
    } catch (e) {
      console.errpr(e);
    }
  },

  mounted () {

    let elements = 90
    const datapresent = []

    let test = firstpoint

    for (let i = 0; i <= elements; i++) {
      datapresent.push(test, 50, 150, 200, 180, 200, 150)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access it as `this.firstpoint`, not `firstpoint`.

But since you are fetching the data asynchronously, it's likely that `mounted()` will be called *before* the request has completed, which means `this.firstpoint` will not have the data yet.

Is there any particular reason why you have separated the code like you have between `created` and `mounted`? You can't control when these methods are called, so you have no guarantee that `this.firstpoint` will be initialized by the time `mounted` is called.

You can try any of:

- Merge the `mounted` code into the `created` code to ensure the correct execution order.
- Move the `mounted` code into a `watch` on `firstpoint` so it will execute once `firstpoint` has been initialized.
- Store the axios promise on the instance so you can `await` it within the `mounted` hook, although it is a bit convoluted:

```js
async created() {
  try {
    this.promise = axios.get(
      "https://k67r3w45c4.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/TwitterTrends"
    );
    const res = await this.promise;
    this.firstpoint = res.data[0].TweetVolume;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
},

async mounted() {
  await this.promise;

  // Now this.firstpoint is initialized, do your thing here
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, it totally works. First time to axios, don't know about the promise before, going to study more. Thanks again so much.

Comment: This problem isn't specific to axois, it's all about asynchronous code. I recommend researching async javascript and promises; there's lots of guides and tutorials about it.